# ASP.Net Session inconsistencies with Cache-Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, cache-control

We are facing a strange issue with ASP.Net session state. We have a legacy application for browsing user accounts that uses session state to store some objects, like the currently opened account number.

After a recent change wherein we added a `Cache-Control` header with `no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate`, we randomly started losing the account number from the session state. What was odd though that when a NullReference exception is throws as a result of accessing the session object that is supposed to exist (from `Page_PreRender`), and when this exception propagates to `Application_Error` where we are redirecting to a custom error page, the exact same session object now magically has the account number (we print it above the stack trace).

Here is how my `Application_Error` looks like in the `global.asax`:

```
Session["ServerLastError"] = (System.Exception)Server.GetLastError();
Server.Execute("~/ApplicationError.aspx");
Server.ClearError();
```

Now I did some digging and I read somewhere that the session is reset in `Application_Error`. However, how is the missing data mysteriously reappearing? And how can our `Cache-Control` settings be affecting this?

Unfortunately due to enterprise restrictions, I cannot post a lot of code here, but please let me know if any piece of code is required to identify the issue, and I'll try to share it.

Any clue what's going on here?

Comment: Are you deploying you application on one server? or you have load balancer?

Comment: @HazemTorab We have a server farm, but we use sticky sessions from the load balancer (meaning if myapp.mycompany.com takes John Doe to webServer6, they'll remain on that until they log out). And our session storage is InProc.